# How to connect protobuf.js from nodejs to client?

Tags: node.js, angular, api, protocol-buffers, protobuf.js

I got a problem that I'm not able to understand how to connect node.js backend API with Front-end application written in Angular. Can anyone help me with it?

I don't understand how should I write data with protobuf.js and consume it at the client side. I was started to use [this library](https://protobufjs.github.io/protobuf.js/) - Protobuf.js - but still I don't have a clue how to do simple API with it.

Thank you for help!

Comment: Would you consider incorporating gRPC (a better version of REST) into your API? It would be a lot easier to use protobufs with gRPC than without it.

Comment: Yes, it could be a good way to do that. But I heard that gRPC doesn't have good support in Angular with some kind of abstraction layer.